# ajax function which is supposed to update a page with new DB info is acting as it should

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a rudimentary chat app using PHP and I would like the page to update every 5 or so seconds with new messages that once sent get stored in a Mysql Database. This is my "webmessenger.php":

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
#content{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
}
</style>
  <body>
<div id = "container">

</div>
    <form action="webmessenger.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name = "message"/>
     <input type = "submit" value = "send"/>
    </form>
  </body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function loadlink(){
    $('#container').load('update.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
</script>
<?php
include("update.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli("SERVER IP", "USER", "PASS", "DB NAME");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
$message = $_POST['message'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` (text) VALUES ('$message')";
$mysqli->query($sql); 
}
?>
</html>
```

this code successfully prints out the search bar, and the last known entries into the DB since I included update.php which contacts the DB and prints each row which contains a message. However, the periodic refresh with ajax is not happening because when you open two windows and send a message on one window, it never pops up on the other.

This is update.php for reference:

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("DB IP", "USER", "PASS", "DB NAME");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `messages`";
 
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

 
if($res->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
$rownum=$row["id"];

 echo $row["text"]."<br />";

 }

}
else
{
 echo "No Record Found!";
}
?>
```

If anyone could help me out and let me know why the function is not working the way it should, that'd be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `include("update.php");` needs to be within `<div id="container">`

Comment: The part that does the db insert when a new message comes in should be right at the top of the file, before `<html>`

Comment: Use your browser devtools network tab to monitor the ajax requests, check the request and response for expected values and error messages.  Make sure you have php error reporting enabled while you debug.

Comment: **Warning** your code is subject to **SQL injection**. Never concatenate untrusted input with SQL code, use parameterized queries.

Comment: @James in the console it says $ cannot be recognized inside of the ajax function